# Unable to get max partition number using partition function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, function, sql-server-2008, partitioning

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(MAX($PARTITION.FacInterestFebosSumVolEod_201901_H_PFN(LoadstatusId)), 0) + 1 AS NextPartitionId
FROM  
    CIL.FacInterestFebosSumVolEod_201901_H;
```

This query is working perfectly fine in production environment and returning 21 as the output. But when I am running it in the Test environment, it's returning 1, even though there are values existing for this partition function.

Is there any link which we need to create between table and partition function?

Below is the crate statement for partition function present in test.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [FacInterestFebosSumVolEod_201901_H_PFN](BIGINT) 
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1273497450, 1273498380, 1273498910)
```

The output of the above query should be 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is using `LoadstatusId` from the `FacInterestFebosSumVolEod_201901_H` table to determine the partition number so the highest partition function boundary will be returned only if data actually exists in the table for the specified partition. Consider querying the `sys.partition_range_values_functions` catalog view to determine the max boundary for the function.

```
SELECT TOP(1) prv.value
FROM sys.partition_functions AS pf
JOIN sys.partition_range_values AS prv ON prv.function_id = pf.function_id
WHERE pf.name = N'FacInterestFebosSumVolEod_201901_H_PFN'
ORDER BY prv.boundary_id DESC;
```